# Bizzare eror - invalid syntax on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have this bizzare error on google colab where although syntay corret I get the following error.

```
  File "<ipython-input-9-7ae5bccf3789>", line 32
    NAME = f"{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}-{SEQ_LEN}-SEQ-{FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT}-PRED-{int(time.time())}"
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I run the same in local jupyter notebook and there is no error
Any ideas why

Comment: Presumably they run different versions of python? `f` strings are relatively new.

Comment: f-strings will cause a syntax error on any Python version `< 3.6`. Also, it is possible the syntax error is few lines above that.

Comment: f-strings are only available after python 3.5 I believe. The interpreter of  Colab might be <=3.4 .

Comment: Yes, thanks that was the error, runtimes !!!!

Comment: For the record, Colaboratory appears to currently be using 3.6.6. (assuming you actually open a Python 3 document and not a Python 2 one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I created the notebook from google drive and by default it creates python2 book, by changing the runtime to python3, error was gone.